# NSRect Size to Fill Screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nswindow

How do i get the current size of the screen no matter the resolution change in xcode so that i can adjust my NSRect size to be maximized or take up the screen according to the resolution ? What do I need to add?  Would it be something to the NSWindow?

```
 NSRect panelRect = [[self window] frame];
    panelRect.size.height = _HEIGHT;
    panelRect.size.width = _WIDTH;
    panelRect.origin.x = 0;
    panelRect.origin.y = 0;
    [[self window] setFrame:panelRect display:NO];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]`?  If you want to exclude the menubar, you can subtract the menubar height from the NSRect's height. (It's around 20 pixels)

Edit: If you want your window to be resized from the start, you can put the method above in your controller's awakeFromNib and use NSWindow's `setFrame:display:` to resize it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CGDisplayBounds`, which returns a `CGRect` containing the screen's bounds (origin and size) in global coordinates.

You can use `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback` to be notified when a display configuration changes, which includes when its resolution is changed.

[*Quartz Display Services Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070)